# ireport cannot recognize the table from oracle 11g database

Tags: oracle11g, ireport

I am a beginner to ireports.I want to create an ireport with oracle 11g using the default tables present in xe. I used EMP table from xe and it showed error ORA-00942 table or view does not exist when i run the query select * from EMP.
Please help!!!

Comment: EMP belongs to user Scott. Are you connected as Scott?

Comment: no.I just logged in with system username.Can u please tell how that works?

Comment: There's too many things to write so I posted an *answer* instead of a *comment*; have a look, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, you should connect to user that contains tables you'd like to use in the report you're creating. So, if it is `EMP` table and it belongs to Scott, connect as Scott.

By default, its username/password combination is `scott`/`tiger` (all lower case). There's a chance that it (user) is locked. If so, connect to the database via SQL*Plus or SQL Developer or any other tool you use (as a privileged user, such as `SYS` or `SYSTEM` if there's no other you have - I presume you don't) and do the following:

```
alter user scott account unlock;
alter user scott identified by tiger;
```

After that, establish connection to Scott in iReport (providing previously mentioned credentials) and you should be able to query the `EMP` table.